# Averaging a set of percentages between certain important levels

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet, called "To Do", with set of percentages in column `E` and importance levels in column `A`:

[image: screenshot depicting the spreadsheet with the data]

On another spreadsheet, I'm entering a formula to calculate the average of these percentages, but only those between certain importance levels:

[image: screenshot depicting the spreadsheet with the formula]

<sub>[See it on googledocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtplORbvSu2rdDhicFVmRl9jLXlJUjd6U1hrQnJVWnc&usp=sharing)</sub>

---

This is the formula in question, indented for easier reading:

```
=TO_PERCENT(
     DIVIDE(
         SUMIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<2000", 'To Do'!E3:E) 
       - SUMIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<=1000", 'To Do'!E3:E), 
         MAX(
             COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<2000") 
           - COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<=1000"), 
             1
         )
     )
 )
```

Is there any better way to do this?

I originally wanted to use `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS`, but it said:

> error: Unknown function name

Comment: Ask Google to add `SUMIFS()` / `COUNTIFS()` / `AVERAGEIF()` ?

Comment: But seriously, there is a scripting language inside Google Spreadsheets that allows you to write your own worksheet functions, but I don't know anything about it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/can-we-review-spreadsheet-formulas)

Comment: Averaging percentages sounds like a suspicious mathematical technique. Are you sure that it makes sense to do that? (We have no idea what problem you are really trying to solve, so we have no context with which to help you catch logic errors.)

Answer (score 7):

As @200_success pointed out in [his comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), averaging percentages is a *suspicious mathematical technique*.

Each *task* in the TODO list could have its own *weight*, or *relative value* - a number that represents a chunk of progress towards "done"; then you can calculate a percentage by adding up the relative weights of all completed tasks (or more accurately, of a value derived from that task's %completed and weight), and dividing by the sum of the weights of all tasks.

---

I haven't played much with [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets), but I know [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) pretty well; the formula you've come up with is exactly the kind of formula I'd have used in Excel 2003, before `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` were introduced in Excel 2007.

When I enter a formula in a spreadsheet, I want to be able to copy that formula over to the next cell, without having to modify it. This involves a number of principles:

- **Don't hard-code cell references**. In Excel I would have used *names* and/or *tables* - not sure [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) supports that, but in any case if none of that is supported you can still, and should, use *absolute cell references* - refer to `'To Do'!$A:$A` and `'To Do'!$E:$E`. Not sure what `A3:A` refers to.
- **Don't hard-code your variables**. If each column is going to use a different set of `[Priority]` values, `"<2000"` and `"<=1000"` shouldn't be hard-coded. You can insert two rows above row 1, and put `1000` in row 1 and `2000` in row 2, so instead of `"<2000"` you'll have `"<" & A$2`, and instead of `"<=1000"` you'll have `"<=" & A$1`.

Lastly, I find

```
MAX(COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<2000") - COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<=1000"), 1)
```

is easier to read as

```
MAX(1, COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<2000") - COUNTIF('To Do'!A3:A, "<=1000"))
```

But the reason you're taking the `MAX` here, is to avoid a division by zero; by dividing by 1 whenever that's the case, you're showing mathematically incorrect results.

In Excel I'd wrap the division with an `IFERROR`, and return a string such as `"-"` when I'm dividing by zero. This accurately reports "this category is irrelevant", rather than "this category is 100% done".

---

Another simple option would be to add a column in the TODO list, to identify the actual priority level (which you currently have as a wasted row between each group); then a simple `SUMIF` / `COUNTIF` can do the trick: you only account for rows with a given `[PriorityCode]` value.

That's actually a "smell": your `[Priority]` values currently encode two values: the *priority group*, and the *priority level*, within that group.

Comment: I guess you've found your mug now ;)

Comment: `A3:A` means "All cells in the `A` column starting with the third-down", since I don't care about column headings. It's okay to hard-code my importance ranges in the same way it's okay for window managers to hard-code their layer levels (e.g. always-on-top = 10,000, modal = 5,000, normal = 0, etc.) since `Immediate` tasks will _**never**_ have a value `<0` or `>=1000`, etc. Somehow you didn't see that **column `A` has all the priority levels**, where `0` is highest and `9999` is lowest.

Comment: No, it's not ok, and yes I've seen what column A contains. You'll have 9 columns with 9 almost-identical formulas that only differ by what ranges in column A are being accounted for. What I'm saying is that if you had another column to hold the "priority groups" for each row, you could get what you need without having to subtract the "not in range" values - in fact there wouldn't be a need for a "range" at all. Just have a column that contains "High" for all such rows, and "Low" for all low-priority tasks, and so on: you're making this much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I didn't know about `A3:A` though, that's interesting. Doesn't work in Excel though.

Comment: The range is there because these have finer priorities than just the groups. If I only needed `0` through `9`, I'd only use `0` through `9`.

Comment: I know, that's not what I'm saying - by encoding **both** the *priority* and the *priority group* in that column, you've created a problem that requires `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` to elegantly solve. Make it two columns, problem solved: one for the *priority group*, another for the *priority level*, and now `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF` works. And I'd have another column with a *weight*, so that the aggregated %'s can be accurately calculated.

Comment: That seems like unneeded complexity... your solution seems to be "add another 2 columns that represent already-present information so that you can use use more formulas to come up with the same result".

Answer (score 5):

**Use a pivot**

Your approach works, and I'll give you that. I feel you are overcomplicating something that is, on the whole, quite simple. Instead of using numbers 1-10,000 to define priority, why not use a simple method like numbers `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and just pivot them? Or maybe to make it more clear, normalize to something like `{"1-Immediate", "2-Very High", "3-High", "4-Medium", "5-Low", "6-Very Low", "7-On Hold", "8-Impossibru", "9-Done"}` ?

Edit: Mind you, percentages can still be used, it just seems very odd to aggregate aggregated values.

Comment: could you define "pivot"?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en